# jQuery Accordion Menu With Enabled/Disabled Links

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I have an accordion-type menu which has gradually evolved and is now almost working as I want. It has three levels: country, region and province. My aim is that when you click on a country, it slides down to reveal the regions. Then once it has done that, clicking the country again links to a new page. Similarly, clicking on a region slides down a list of provinces and then clicking on the region again links to a page relevant to the region.

To do that I have to have links that are diabled and enabled by jQuery according to the state of the accordion. I think that can be done with preventDefault(), but I haven't succeeded in making it work yet.

```
function(e){
e.preventDefault()
}
```

This [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28hh2ksk/13/) shows my current state of progress. There's no link on "France" at the moment so that the regions can slide down. There are links on the individual regions, so at the moment it won't progress to showing the provinces.

I think I'm not far away but all attempts at inserting a preventDefault() line (or return false) have failed to get the desired effect. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

With Jako's help I have made good progress. The original problem is solved. I've also added a "Close" button at the bottom so that a user can keep the menu tidy and manageable if they choose to do lots of clicking. I seem to have just one problem left now: After accordioning-down the menu (say, France) and closing it again, clicking on "France" again opens the link instead of opening the accordion again. In other words the "return false" doesn't work after opening and closing once. Can anyone guide me from here?

I've updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28hh2ksk/21/) to reflect the current progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'override' the link action, you may simply use "return false";

```
$(".leftnav a").click(
function(){
   var sub_nav = $(this).parent().find('ul').first();
   if(sub_nav.length > 0 && !sub_nav.is(":visible")) {
       sub_nav.slideDown(800);
       return false;
    }
});
```

On jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zrhefp2p/1/

Comment: Thanks Jako. That almost works but all the province fields open in response to clicking country. Instead of just opening the regions, and then clicking the region to open the provinces under it. Any idea how I can tweak your suggestion to make that happen?

Comment: If you replace 
       var sub_nav = $(this).parent().find('ul'); by 
       var sub_nav = $(this).parent().find('ul').first(); that should be the behavior you are looking for

Comment: Great, you may want to mark the question as answered.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Now I'm going to have a try at putting in some sort of "close" link, because I can't use the conventional method.

Comment: I've got the "close" link working (see the updated JSFiddle linked in my edit of the original post) but on clicking the top level of the menu a second time (after closing it) the "return false" doesn't work. The menu then follows the link instead of opening the accordion. Any more thoughts?

Comment: I think your updated script is not closing the correct element (sliding up the  a element instead of the ul parent, which property :visible is still true). I would rather slide up the ul parent, seems to work fine on this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/28hh2ksk/22/